# PHP Pagination Problem

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I had search through many websites and tried the different ways provided online, but it cant seen to work. It does not load the information when I click next, last, first, previous. It only loads the first page's result. Please help! Thank you in advance.

```
function retrieveName($fieldName)
{   
    $i=1;
    if(isset($_GET[$fieldName]))
    {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());           
        mysql_select_db("intern") or die(mysql_error()); 


         //This checks to see if there is a page number. If not, it will set it to page 1 

         if (!(isset($pagenum))) 

         { 

         $pagenum = 1; 

         } 

         //Here we count the number of results 

         $intern = $_GET[$fieldName];
         $data = mysql_query("SELECT p.`internName`, p.`internNRIC`, c.`internSchName` FROM `personaldetails` p, `currentinstitution` c WHERE c.`internNRIC`= p.`internNRIC` AND p.`internName` like '%$intern%' || p.`internNRIC` like '%$intern%' || c.`internSchName` like '%$intern%' GROUP BY p.internNRIC") or die(mysql_error()); 

         $rows = mysql_num_rows($data); 

         //This is the number of results displayed per page 

         $page_rows = 1;            


         //This tells us the page number of our last page 

         $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows); 

         //this makes sure the page number isn't below one, or more than our maximum pages 

         if ($pagenum < 1) 

         { 

         $pagenum = 1; 

         } 

         elseif ($pagenum > $last) 

         { 

         $pagenum = $last; 

         } 

         //This sets the range to display in our query 

         $max = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows; 

    PRODUCTION.   //This is your query again, the same one... the only difference is we add $max into it

         $data_p = mysql_query("SELECT p.`internName`, p.`internNRIC`, c.`internSchName` FROM `personaldetails` p, `currentinstitution` c WHERE c.`internNRIC`= p.`internNRIC` AND p.`internName` like '%$intern%' || p.`internNRIC` like '%$intern%' || c.`internSchName` like '%$intern%' GROUP BY p.internNRIC $max ") or die(mysql_error()); 


         //This is where you display your query results

         while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data_p )) 
         {      
            echo $i. ".";
            echo " NRIC : <a href='InternInfo.php?id='" . $row['internNRIC'] . ">".$row['internNRIC'] ."</a>";
            echo "</br><br/>";
            echo "  Name : ". $row['internName'] . "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Name of School :" . $row['internSchName'];
            echo "</br><br/>";              
            $i++;                       
         } 

         echo "<p>";


         // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages

         echo " --Page $pagenum of $last-- <p>";


         // First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we generate links to the first page, and to the previous page.

         if ($pagenum == 1) 

         {

         } 

         else 

         {
            echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=1&searchIntern=$intern'> <<-First</a> ";             
            echo "---Interns Search---";            
            $previous = $pagenum-1;         
            echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$previous&searchIntern=$intern'> <-Previous</a> ";           

         } 

         //This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the Next and Last links

         if ($pagenum == $last) 

         {

         } 

         else
         {          
            $next = $pagenum+1;             
            echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$next&searchIntern=$intern'>Next -></a> ";           
            echo "---Interns Search---";            
            echo " <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last&searchIntern=$intern'>Last ->></a> ";

         } 
    }else echo "Please enter your search.";
}
```

Comment: It seems your code is not prepared agains SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% about this, but it looks like you're using a local variable for `$pagenum` when you want to use either a parameter (good idea) or a global variable such as `$_GET['pagenum']`. You're also leaving yourself open to SQL injection. Use mysql_real_escape_string on all variables which need to be used in queries (like **$intern**).

Comment: I took your advise and added $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum']    if (!(isset($pagenum))) 
   
    { 
   
    $pagenum = 1; 
   
    } 

   $pagenum = $_GET['pagenum'];
    //Here we count the number of results 
   
    $intern = $_GET[$fieldName];
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT p.`internName`, p.`internNRIC`, c.`internSchName` FROM `personaldetails` p, `currentinstitution` c WHERE c.`internNRIC`= p.`internNRIC` AND p.`internName` like '%$intern%' || p.`internNRIC` like '%$intern%' || c.`internSchName` like '%$intern%' GROUP BY p.internNRIC") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Are you passing pagenum in the URL? EG: yoursite.thing/index.php?pagenum=1

Comment: OR, are you using `$pagenum = isset( $_GET[ 'pagenum' ] )?$_GET[ 'pagenum' ]: 1;`

Comment: passing it in the URL                                                 <a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?pagenum=$last&searchIntern=$intern

Answer (score 0):

As @cwallenpoole says, it looks like `$pagenum` is scoped outside of the function, and I'm guessing the function is written assuming that `register_globals` is on, which is generally [a very bad thing](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php). I've seen this cause plenty of issues when moving an old (inherited) site to a new server.

To fix that specific problem, replace:

```
     if (!(isset($pagenum))) 

     { 

     $pagenum = 1; 

     }
```

with this:

```
$pagenum = isset($_REQUEST['pagenum']) ?
    (int)$_REQUEST['pagenum'] :
    1;
```

This sets `$pagenum` to the request's `pagenum` value, and defaults to `1` if the page number isn't in the request. It also casts the value to an `int` which should at least stop *one* injection attack vector. The rest of the function is another matter...